# How can I transform a Http error before its handled with subscribe()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular2 component that is using a service which uses `Http` to make a HTTP request.

The service looks something like:

```
export class AuthenticateService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public authenticateUser(username: string, password: string) : Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3002/admin/login", {
        username: username, password: password
    })
    .map((res: Response) => {
        //I can fiddle with non-error responses here, but if an error happens then this doesnt get called
        return res.json() as User;
    }); 
  }
```

And the component looks something like:

```
export class LoginFormComponent {

  userRequest : Observable<User>;

  constructor(private _authenticateService: AuthenticateService, private _router: Router) {}

doLogin() : void {
    this.userRequest = this._authenticateService.authenticateUser(this.form.username, this.form.password);

    this.userRequest.subscribe(user => {
        this._router.navigateByUrl("/user");
    }, error => {
        //this is where I just want the 'errorMessage' property, not the entire ResponseBody object
        console.log("Error object looks like: ", error);
        this.errorMessage = error.json().errorMessage;
    });
}
```

}

The service returns an Observable which the component subscribes to. However, when the `error` function is executed (due to a HTTP request returning a non-200 status code), I get the full HTTP response object passed as the `error` parameter to the error handling function.

How can I transform it at the service level to just return the `errorMessage` portion? All I want to deal with in my error handling function is the string error message, it shouldnt have to deal with an entire HTTP response object or even know that HTTP is a thing.

I am used to Promises and still trying to get my head around RxJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `catch()` operator:

```
this.userRequest
.catch(e => Observable.throw(e.json().errorMessage))
// or just .catch(e => throw e.json().errorMessage)
.subscribe(user => {
    this._router.navigateByUrl("/user");
}, error => {
    //this is where I just want the 'errorMessage' property, not the entire ResponseBody object
    console.log("Error object looks like: ", error);
    this.errorMessage = error;
});
```

Comment: I guess this should be `.catch(e => Observable.throw(e.json().errorMessage)`.

Comment: It should even be `.catch(resp => Observable.throw(resp.json().errorMessage))`, to do what the OP wants, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Depends on what you try to accomplish. But I agree it doesn't make to much sense to have  the `, error => { ... }` part in this case.  Thanks for the hint anyway.